# Copying Dlls to VS IDE Folder with VSIX

Tags: visual-studio, dll, deployment

I`m creating VS2017 Extension, There some DLLs my Interface depends on, I would like to copy these DLLs to this folder:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE
```

I have the DLLs added to my project with IncludeInVsix set to true in the properties window.

I made sure of that by changing VSIX to ZIP and the DLLs are there. However they are not copied to the IDE folder, and though I have to copy them manually to get the extension to work.

Any idea how to accomplish this ?

Comment: request elevation (install to all users) so that the Installer can copy the data to Program files directory

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying dlls to VS IDE Folder, it is recommended to use [ProvideBindingPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.providebindingpathattribute.aspx) or [ProvideCodeBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.providecodebaseattribute.aspx) attributes to tell VS where to look for your dlls.